# Asses calibration result using OpenCV vs Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, camera-calibration

I'm working on a project where i have to calibrate the camera in order to calculate the camera matrix and use it for other processes

I calibrated the camera using Zahng's method (Checkerboard) and performed the calibration using two different tools:
1- Matlab calibration tool
2-OpenCV method (cv2.calibrateCamera())

for both methods i used the same images (16 images).

**the result form Matlab**

```
4380.06266797091                0                0 
    0                    4374.31691291339        0
949.990213743877         664.725183192415        1

#Radial Distortion Coefficient
-0.355521260561817  1.30195034883959

#tangational Distortion Coefficient
0   0 

#average REPROJECTION ERROR
0.513903578285060
----------------------------------------------------
```

**The results form OpenCV code**

```
#camera matrix
mtx [[4.38350928e+03 0.00000000e+00 9.73653727e+02]
    [0.00000000e+00 4.37873075e+03 6.68924323e+02]
    [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]]

#Distortion Coefficients
dist [[-3.59709752e-01  3.91496111e+00  3.43950578e-03  1.01871917e-03
      -6.21911790e+01]]
```

***So my questions are:***

1-Which results are considered to be more accurate as the Principal point differs a little bit

2-Why OpenCV considers 5 Distortion Coefficients whereas Matlab considers 4 (two are zero where in Opencv are not!)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: See https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/single-camera-calibrator-app.html#. In Matlab you can choose either 2 or 3 radial distortion coefficients and get the 2 tangential coefficients as well. See https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html. So in Opencv you get 5 coefficients: 3 radial and 2 tangential. The order is different in the return coefficients from OpenCV and Matlab. But the results should be equivalent if the distortion equations are the same. See what you get if you use 3 radial coefficients in Matlab.

Comment: In OpenCV, your tangential coefficients are very small 3.43950578e-03  1.01871917e-03 and likely are negligible. In Matlab you got 0 and 0 for the two.  Differences may be due to precision. But may be negligible in their effects.

Comment: Did you include skew in Matlab. I believe OpenCV includes it.

Comment: @fmw42 and what about the differences in the Principal point? is this because the different number of the calculated Distortion coefficients in both methods?

Comment: You have not shown those difference. Please do so.  But first make both models equivalent as described above.

Comment: @fmw42. I've performed the calibration using matlab and by setting 3 radial distortions and two tangential. the result for the 3 radial Dist is :[ -0.350078395972537 2.14882923100741 -18.7121657142504], Skew Factor is -4.05660047401965. SO what can be said whe we compare them again with the ones from openCV?

Comment: @fmw42. and the camera matrix after doing so is  [4377.43742812293 0 0]
[-4.05660047401965 4372.39753819076    0]
[962.409891899587 675.729500520219 1]

Comment: @fmw42. Looking at both results. what is the criterion that tells me which results i should use? or both results are same and therefore both can be used with out effecting o another results?

Comment: Which one has the smaller residuals?  Or project points from 3D to 2D in both and see how different they are. They are likely insignificant or within error tolerances.

Comment: @fmw42. Do you mean to compare the back projection error for both?

Comment: You can project either way 2D to 3D or 3D to 2D so long as both models use the same coordinates. Use the ground plane (Z=0) for all 3D points. Then look at the differences in the output coordinates of the projection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments have lead me to the solution of the problem. Credit to @fmw42

Comment: Please post your results for other to see. It would be interesting to find out if one is significantly better than the other. Also your method would be educational.